# How to make sure access_token is always valid before calling any API (without using Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, asynchronous, es6-promise

I have been working on using react to call APIs and I am so confused about the async nature in JS.. the main purpose was to use the access token to call an API for some info (asset count within data catalog), and if the token has expired when calling the API then I will update the access token first and then call the API using the updated token, simple as that. The way that I am doing this is defining two functions `updateToken()` and  `retrieveAssetCount()`. However, when the token expires, there is still 401 error saying token is expired and I have to refresh the page once to make the page show properly.

```
class Search extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          totalAssets:"Loading...",
        }
        this.updateToken = this.updateToken.bind(this);
        this.retrieveAssetCount = this.retrieveAssetCount.bind(this);
      }
      updateToken(){
        fetch(proxyUrl+tokenUrl,requestOptions).then((response) => response.json()).then((responseJson)=>{
          sessionStorage.setItem('accessToken',responseJson.access_token);
          sessionStorage.setItem('expiresOn',responseJson.expires_on);
        })
      }
      
      retrieveAssetCount(){
        fetch(<api endpoint>,{
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{'Authorization':'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken'),
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({keywords:''})}).then(res => res.json()).then(data => 
        this.setState({totalAssets:data['@search.count']}))
        }
    componentDidMount(){
      let currentTime = new Date().getTime()/1000
      if (sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken') === null || sessionStorage.getItem('expiresOn') 
          <=currentTime+60){
        console.log('token is bad');
        this.updateToken(()=>{this.retrieveAssetCount()})
      }else{
        console.log('token is good');
        this.retrieveAssetCount()
    }
}
    }
```

Comment: You're passing a callback in the `this.updateToken(()=>{this.retrieveAssetCount()})` call, but `updateToken` does not take a parameter? Don't do that, `return` the promise and chain onto it.

Comment: Btw, there's no reason to `bind` your two methods.

Comment: Hi Beigi, thanks for replying! none of these two functions needs parameters, I was just trying to make sure updateToken was executed first and then the other one. Could you elaborate more on returning the promise? should I do it inside componentDidMount? thanks!

Comment: You need to return the promise from `updateToken` so that you can call `this.updateToken().then(() => this.retrieveAssetCount())` in `componentDidMount`.

Comment: that was helpful, thanks!!